# Draw ball trajectory in mayavi

Tags: python, animation, mayavi

I would like to know how to draw a ball trajectory in Mayavi inside an animation. At the moment I'm using 3 lists to save the historical position of the ball and then using a plot3d to do it, but I cannot see the lines and after some time some errors arrise.

```
x_hist.append(bx)
y_hist.append(by)
z_hist.append(bz)
mlab.plot3d(x_hist, y_hist, z_hist, color=(1,0,0), line_width=100)
```

The errors are:

> Coincident points in polyline...can't compute normals Could not
>   generate normals for line. Skipping to next.

Witch could be the best way to animate a ball trajectory in mayavi?

The sample code with the ball moving can be found on:  http://pastebin.com/fEgL7vYi

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a curve object:

```
curve = visual.curve(color=curve_color, radius=curve_radius)
```

and then using this method for adding more points:

```
curve.extend(point_history)
```

And point_history is a list of  visual.vector with the X, Y, and Z positions.

```
arr = visual.vector(float(bx), float(by), float(bz))
point_history.append(arr)
```

But there is a catch: the positions cannot repeat themselves inside the list!